# Структура базы данных на JSON

Tags: json, база-данных

**Подскажите кто как создает структуру базы данных?** 
Есть игра, где можно покупать товары на рынке и продавать их компьютерным торговцам. Обычно компьютеру продавать не выгодно, но иногда случаются ситуации, когда можно купить на рынке и сразу продать одному из Торговцев. 
Интересует ваше мнение, как бы вы сделали структуру БД под эту задачу и почему? 
Я сделал так (упаковав в JSON):

```
{
    "Товар 1": {
        "цена продажи": 1310,                  # По чем можно продать компьютерному торговцу
        "кому выгодно продавать": "Торговец 1",      # Какому именно торговцу
        "по чем я могу купить": 21867,           # Последняя цена по которой я мог купить для продажи
        "profit": 0,                   # Сколько раз за все сканирования было выгодное соотношение 
        "история изменения цен": {                     # История сканов, если цена менялась
            "05-03-2024/18:10:29": 16749,
            "05-03-2024/19:03:56": 17499,
            "05-03-2024/19:13:17": 23499,
            "05-03-2024/21:20:46": 21867
        }
    },
    "Товар 2": {
        "цена продажи": 3150,
        "кому выгодно продавать": "Торговец 3",
        "по чем я могу купить": 5816,
        "profit": 1,
        "история изменения цен": {
            "05-03-2024/18:10:29": 6360,
            "05-03-2024/19:03:56": 6008,
            "05-03-2024/19:13:17": 5880,
            "05-03-2024/21:20:46": 2878,
            "05-03-2024/21:42:28": 5816
        }
    }, ...
}
```

Есть хорошие мысли, как можно было бы сделать лучше?

Comment: *Есть хорошие мысли?* Угу. Надо изучить теорию "базостроения", хотя бы основы, и делать по науке. Или получится... в общем, плохо получится.

Comment: json - формат данных в основном предназначенный для обработки сведений. Если речь идёт про их хранение - узнайте что такое НФ в базах данных.